# How to draw a perfect hexagon with three divs?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Putting a div to the center of the viewport with `position:absolute` and `top:50%;` `left:50%;` `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`.

and using before and after elements with `rotate(60deg)` and `rotate(-60deg)`.

setting the divs `box-sizing: border-box;` `border:1px solid blue;` `height:40px;` and `20*2*3^(1/2)` seems to be `69.28xxxxxxx`, so I set the width as that.

but the result seems there are some unperfect pixels at the border crossing point. I don't know how to fix it.

browser: chrome
editor:bracket

http://jsfiddle.net/gonejack/hYN67/

Comment: Can you show the fiddle?

Comment: Go to http://jsfiddle.net/ and try to recreate your problem, then save it and give us the link.

Comment: You can get some tips from http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/hexagon-with-shadow/

Comment: Doesn't work in FF (FF is old). In Chrome it's ugly (Chrome is ugly). It works in Safari (Go !).

Comment: Try not to use floats for pixel dimensions.

Comment: try that but still the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The borders might be distorting the shapes in your fiddle.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zqS3Q/ and replace with this code to see a solid hexagon with no borders:

```
   #container {
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid red;
        margin-top: 10%;
        min-height: 200px;
    }

    #horizontal {
        position: absolute;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        height: 39px;
        width: 66px;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    #horizontal:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 39px;
        width: 66px;
        background-color: blue;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg);
    }


    #horizontal:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 39px;
        width: 66px;
        background-color: blue;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
    }
```

Also, rotated boxes aren't necessarily going to be the exact specified pixel dimensions:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a chrome console bug, the console turn on then the shape would became weird, when the console high enough to give the viewport a scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work if rather than `60deg` in `horizontal:after` you put in `-120deg`. It looks like a rounding error.

http://jsfiddle.net/m3Xx8/

Comment: That fiddle still shows the `60deg` rather than the `-120deg` you specified. Just letting you know.